# Run SQL scripts on windows mobile installer

Tags: windows-mobile, installation

We are working on a Windows Mobile 6.5 application in Visual Studio 2008.
The application is already installed in some devices, and we need to distribute a new version with changes in the database schema (we added a few tables).
Is there a way to make a "patch" windows mobile installer that will replace the application and update the embedded SQL database with some scripts?
In a normal windows installer we would create a custom action in the installation process to apply the changes in the database, but I'm not sure how to do that for Windows Mobile
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAB files don't have any ability to execute SQL directly, though you can create and include a [custom installer DLL](http://www.cnblogs.com/pengai3/archive/2008/10/23/1317391.html) that can perform actions.  Running SQL from C++ isn't a whole lot of fun, though. In reality, it's probably better, and far easier, to just have the new version of the application check the DB scema and update it if required.